# I can't get this Smart Dimmer to work

Tags: electrical, switch, dimmer-switch, smart-switch

- GE Zigbee Smart Dimmer
- I can't get it to turn on
- I have tried 2 different ones and neither will turn on
- The only way we can get them to turn on is by putting both wires in the same hole, but then it obviously won't turn off

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: @MilesBudnek  The instructions  do not show a connection to a neutral.

Comment: @JACK Hmm, you're right.  I assumed that was the same GE Zigbee dimmer I had, which does need a neutral, but I guess not.

Comment: @miles budnek the schematic linked by the op shows line, load and ground only. Some smart switches that do not have proper grounds will not work. My guess that the ground is not a complete circuit back to the main panel.

Comment: It's nicer for everyone if you embed the images directly instead of making people click out to other locations.

Comment: @FreeMan - new/low rep users can't inline directly & the instructions they are given really don't make that clear.

Comment: @Lizzie C  Are there additional wiring diagrams that show connecting the white wires in the box to the neutral on your switch?

Comment: well, @Tetsujin, that's dumb... Not your fault or any new user's fault, but dumb none the less.

Comment: @FreeMan - Agree.  I guess we could raise it on main Meta if it hasn't been already. It's always odd as a high rep user if you're on a stack you have low rep (like me on this one) because you see the 'newbie' limitations afresh, long after you'd forgotten all about them ;)

Comment: Ah, that diagram in the instructions is the "before" image.  That switch _does_ require a neutral; it's just shown in a later image.

Comment: @MilesBudnek  What later image are you seeing this neutral connection?

Comment: @AlaskaMan There's a later diagram in the instructions.  I can't find the official Jasco download link, but here they are on a super sketchy manuals download site: [instructions](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/1462411/Ge-Zb3001.html)

Comment: The drawing contradicts the written instructions.

Answer (score 2):

There are completed instructions on the web. You will have to use the white jumper included with the switch or get a 6" piece of white #14 AWG and connect it to the two white wired in the box and then connect the other end to the neutral terminal on the switch. Read your complete instructions, especially #10 under the "wire strip lengths".

Here is a cut & paste provided by Harper that shows the missing part of the instructions. I have edited it into my answer with his blessing.

[image]

Comment: And #10 is in the next column, and OP's photo shows the sheet folded so that is just barely concealed.  There are 5 more steps on it.  Normally I would judge OP harshly, but the drawing and written instructions do indeed contradict each other.  I cut-n-pasted the missing instructions here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivngj.png feel free to add it to your answer.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica  I think the OP's first drawing is the switch being replaced and the upper right smaller picture is the new dimmer. See that the yokes are different.